# How to prefill ActiveAdmin form value from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-activerecord

In the following code, how does one populate a prefilled form field with a value from another model into the ActiveAdmin form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person do

  index do
    column :forename
    column :surname
    column :code do |p|
      MyCode.find_by_person_id(p.id).code
    end
    column :updated_at
    default_actions
  end

  filter :forename
  filter :surname

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Person" do
      f.input :forename
      f.input :surname
      # How to get a value here, e.g. MyCode.find_by_person_id(p.id).code as above
      #f.input :code, :input_html => { :value => value??? }, as: :hidden
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the problem you faced while using the approach you've commented?

Comment: I was not aware of `f.object`! Sorry for such a simple question, but also the coverage on it is not really good, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, activeadmin's DSL is specific, got to get used to it. good you found the solution!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [nistvan commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369075/1373324), `has_one` relationship fetches the related object into the form object, thus my problem could be solved with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person do

  index do
    column :forename
    column :surname
    column :code do |p|
      MyCode.find_by_person_id(p.id).code
    end
    column :updated_at
    default_actions
  end

  filter :forename
  filter :surname

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Person" do
      f.input :forename
      f.input :surname
      f.input :code, :input_html => { :value => f.object.my_code.code }, as: :hidden
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: when a new object will be created then from `f.input :code..` will throw exception

Answer (score 1):

If in your model a Person has_one Code, then `f.input :code` will work fine. Also you don't have to explicit determine the Code in the index block, just: `column :code`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Comment: Won't work currently, `code` is just `attr_accessor`. It's used for processing, e.g. validation until the connection is made.